# Spring 4 / Groovy DSL - autowiring

Tags: java, spring

How do I enable autowiring when using the Groovy DSL in Spring 4?

if my `config.groovy` file currently looks like this:

```
beans {
    mongoClient(com.mongodb.MongoClient)

    hello(org.abiri.HelloImpl) {
        mongoClient = mongoClient
    }
}
```

Previously in XML configuration, we could have done this:

```
<bean id="hello" class="org.abiri.HelloImpl" autowire="byType" />
```

And we could even enable that for the whole file:

```
<beans default-autowire="byType" />
```

What is the equivalent of those XML snippets in the new Groovy DSL, i.e what do I need to do in order for the `mongoClient` to be `autowired` to hello ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
hello(org.abiri.HelloImpl) { bean ->
  bean.autowire = "byType"
}
```

The configuration closure is passed a parameter that you can use to configure things that would be attributes on the `bean` element in an XML configuration. In addition to `autowire` this includes `scope`, `initMethod` and `destroyMethod`.

Comment: Perfect. And how do I enable it by default for the whole file (as with the `<beans default-autowire="byType" />` approach?